# How to add project hosted on github to android studio gradle dependencies? Pom.xml is available

Tags: android, maven, github, android-studio, gradle

I want to add [this](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) project to my Android Studio Gradle dependencies list. `Pom.xml` is available [here](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming/blob/master/pom.xml).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add this library with Gradle.

It doesn't provide an aar format.

You can open an issue and ask the author to push an aar into maven.

Otherwise you have to clone the library and add as a local module.